# Error Undefined index al tratar de subir imagen en php

Tags: php, imagen, undefined

Saludos!
Estoy tratando de subir una imagen desde cualquier directorio del pc, nunca habia intentado esto por eso ando muy perdido, espero me puedan ayudar!
Gracias de adelantado.
Voy a omitir codigo porque son varios archivos.
Tengo el formulario en "agregarProducto.php", ya tiene agregado enctype="multipart/form-data", el codigo principal es esto:

```
    if(isset($_POST["iniciar"])){   
            $conexion = new conexion();
            $foto = $_POST["foto"]; <----Linea 21

            if($conexion->insertarProducto($foto))
            {
                header("Location: productos.php");  
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No se ingreso correctamente el producto.";
            }
        }
```

Dentro del form en html esta el de la imagen:

```
    <input type="file" tabindex="4" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg" class="form-control" id="foto" name = "foto" placeholder="Nombre del producto" maxlength="100" required>
```

Por ultimo se envia a conexion.class.php, el codigo que tengo ahi es este:

```
    public function insertarProducto($foto)
{
    $nombre_img = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Practica/imagenes/';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$nombre_img);
    $consulta = "Call InsertarProducto('".$foto."')";
    if($this->conn->query($consulta)===true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Creo que no se me queda nada! Al enviar los datos me da este error:
Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\Practica\agregarProductos.php on line 21

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta con ' $foto = $_POST["foto"];`, que debes usar siempre $Files

Comment: Cambia la línea 21 por esto: `$foto=$_FILES['foto']['name'];`. Revisa al respecto lo que dice el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php).  Si no se resuelve, pon al menos parte del contenido de tu formulario en la pregunta para revisarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno hace mucho yo hize algo similar con este tutorial :

Prueba con est codigo

```html
   // allow valid image file formats
   if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){   
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize < 5000000)    {
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
    }
    else{
     $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    }
   }
   else{
    $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";  
   }
  }
```

y te recomiendo agregar esta linea de codigo , no la veo en tu codigo:

```
    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice
```

[tutorial](http://www.codingcage.com/2016/02/upload-insert-update-delete-image-using.html)